# Get Values from nested Json Object

Tags: c#, json

I have a nested json format like given below,I need to read all the nodes till the last node to get the node name, node value, attribute name, parent node. I tried using a recursive function to read data but its not working correctly. Please help with a simple solution to read data. (precisely a dynamic one which can handle any number of nodes and attributes)

**Required Output format**

```
   name     |   Value        | IsNode | Parent
------------------------------------------------
 updated    2014-01-01  false   record
 position   ambassador  true    record/person
 first_name Eliyahu     true    record/person/names
 alias      Eli         true    record/person/names/aliases
 country    ISRAEL      true    record/details/countries
 category   DIPLOMAT    false   record
```

**Json Input format**

```
{
  "Node": "record",
  "NodeValue": null,
  "ParentNode": "records",
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Node": "person",
      "NodeValue": null,
      "ParentNode": "record",
      "Nodes": [
        {
          "Node": "title",
          "NodeValue": "Dr",
          "ParentNode": "person",
          "Nodes": [

          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "position",
          "NodeValue": "Ambassador",
          "ParentNode": "person",
          "Nodes": [

          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "names",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "person",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "first_name",
              "NodeValue": "Eliyahu",
              "ParentNode": "names",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Node": "last_name",
              "NodeValue": "BEN TURA",
              "ParentNode": "names",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Node": "aliases",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "names",
              "Nodes": [
                {
                  "Node": "alias",
                  "NodeValue": "BEN TURA,Eli",
                  "ParentNode": "aliases",
                  "Nodes": [

                  ],
                  "Attributes": [

                  ]
                }
              ],
              "Attributes": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Node": "alternative_spelling",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "names",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "agedata",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "person",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "age",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "agedata",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Node": "as_of_date",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "agedata",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Node": "dob",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "agedata",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Node": "deceased",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "agedata",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Key": "ssn",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Key": "e-i",
          "Value": "M"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Node": "details",
      "NodeValue": null,
      "ParentNode": "record",
      "Nodes": [
        {
          "Node": "passports",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "details",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "passport",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "passports",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "country",
                  "Value": ""
                },
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "place_of_birth",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "details",
          "Nodes": [

          ],
          "Attributes": [
            {
              "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
              "Value": "true"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "locations",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "details",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "location",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "locations",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "country",
                  "Value": "SENEGAL"
                },
                {
                  "Key": "city",
                  "Value": "Dakar"
                },
                {
                  "Key": "state",
                  "Value": "Dakar"
                },
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "countries",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "details",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "country",
              "NodeValue": "ISRAEL",
              "ParentNode": "countries",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [

              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "companies",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "details",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "company",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "companies",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "Node": "keywords",
          "NodeValue": null,
          "ParentNode": "details",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Node": "keyword",
              "NodeValue": null,
              "ParentNode": "keywords",
              "Nodes": [

              ],
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Key": "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil",
                  "Value": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Attributes": [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "Attributes": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "Attributes": [
    {
      "Key": "category",
      "Value": "DIPLOMAT"
    },
    {
      "Key": "editor",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Key": "entered",
      "Value": "2010-11-19"
    },
    {
      "Key": "sub-category",
      "Value": "PEP"
    },
    {
      "Key": "uid",
      "Value": "1389120"
    },
    {
      "Key": "updated",
      "Value": "2014-01-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to deserialize the JSON into the following class:

```
public class JsonNodes
{
    public string Node { get; set; }
    public string NodeValue { get; set; }
    public string ParentNode { get; set; }
    public List<JsonNodes> Nodes { get; set; }
    public List<JsonNodesAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class JsonNodesAttribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use this method to print all the values in the required output format using a console application:

```
private static void PrintValues(JsonNodes nodes, string parent)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", nodes.Node));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value: {0}", nodes.NodeValue));
    Console.WriteLine("IsNode: true");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parent: {0}", parent)); 
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (parent == string.Empty)
    {
        parent += nodes.Node;
    }
    else
    {
        parent += string.Format("/{0}", nodes.Node);
    }

    foreach (JsonNodesAttribute attribute in nodes.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", attribute.Key));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value: {0}", attribute.Value));
        Console.WriteLine("IsNode: false");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parent: {0}", parent));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (JsonNodes childNode in nodes.Nodes)
    {
        PrintValues(childNode, parent);
    }
}
```

Let's say you put the JSON to a string variable named `jsonInput`, here's how you deserialize and print all of its values:

```
string jsonInput = ...; // put the above json here
JsonNodes nodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonNodes>(jsonInput);
PrintValues(nodes, string.Empty);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: i have the object format of the json. how can i write a iterative function to read all values(precisely a dynamic one which can handle any number of nodes and attributes)

Comment: See my edited answer, the `PrintValues` method will run recursively until the last node.

Comment: thanks. this help to read all the nodes. But i need to obtain data in a specified format. please see the edited question

Comment: attributes should also have the full path struture

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46590/discussion-between-deepu-and-ekad)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to enumerate your JSON string using [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
void JsonVisitor(JToken node, int indent = 0)
{
    var indentString = new String(' ', indent * 4);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}: {2}", indentString, node["Node"], node["NodeValue"]);
    foreach (var attribute in node["Attributes"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2}", indentString, attribute["Key"], attribute["Value"]);
    }
    foreach (var subNode in node["Nodes"])
    {
        JsonVisitor(subNode, indent + 1);
    }
}
```

You can call it like this (if `jsonString` is your input):

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JsonVisitor(jsonObject.Root);
```